# What notation technique is used to describe Angular syntax?

Tags: angular, notation, bnf

What notation technique is used in [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/) to describe the Angular syntax as, for example,  [Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

```
{{ value_expression | number [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] }}
```

PS

I found the [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation technique but it's not the technique is used to annotate the Angular Docs.

Comment: in this case, `{{` and `}}` are literal your wrote in the .html, the `|` is one option or another, and the `[` `]` and optionals parameters (sorry I don't know the name of the notation)

Answer (score 0):

[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/docs-style-guide#help-with-documentation-style) refers to the [Google developer documentation style guide](https://developers.google.com/style). Google guide refers mainly to [Microsoft Writing Style Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/style-guide/welcome/) along with other published manuals.

Regarding the notation itself, the [Angular documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/README.md) explains the structure of the project and the [tool named dgeni](https://github.com/angular/dgeni) used to generate documentation like in the question.

The documentation generation is based on tags in the source code. In the end, there is no official name like BNF used for all references.